# How to extract a part of the url

Tags: php, url, extract

How can I take out the part of the url after the id name 
Example:

The URL: 
   `localhost/single.php?id=23` 
Extraction 
 `23`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
$url = parse_url('http://localhost/single.php?id=23');
parse_str($url['query'], $values);
echo $values['id']; // outputs 23
```

Comment: What should I write where is the 'query'

Comment: @BogdanConstantin check the edited version

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

In this case I would use

```
$_url = 'localhost/single.php?id=23';
preg_match('/id=([\d]+)/', $_url, $_match);
echo $_match[1]; // 23
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `parse_url()` and then acces the `query` component to get the whole query.
  But if you're only interested in the value of `id` it might be easier to retrieve it using `$_GET["id"]`